# Sometimes I can not find a window by ParentDlg.child_window()

Tags: python, pywinauto

I have just started learning python. Now my work is trying to use pywinauto to do some auto tests. Sometimes I can get one dialog by `ParentDlg.child_window(**criterion)`, sometimes not.

You can think my application(PageManager.exe) has two buttons, [Page1] button and [Page2] button. When application is started, you can click button to start Page.exe process. That means there are two Page.exe at the same time. When Page.exe is started, it starts ImageCalculate.exe. So there are two ImageCalculate.exe two. The parent dialog of ImageCalculate.exe is Page.exe.

When you click [Page1] button, the Page.exe (used for Page1) is displayed and Page.exe (used for Page2) is hid. When you click [Page2] button, the Page.exe (used for Page2) is displayed and Page.exe (used for Page1) is hid.

My problem is when one Page.exe is displayed, such as Page.exe(used for Page1). I can find main dialog of Page.exe by `ParentDlg = Desktop(backend="uia").window(best_match="Page1")`. After that, I use `psutil.pids()` and process name `"ImageCalculate.exe"` to get two PIDs of ImageCalculate.exe, for example, one is 1234, another is 5678. Please attention, two ImageCalculate.exe have almost the same property, same title, class name and so on.
At last I try to get the main dialog of ImageCalculate.exe by `ParentDlg.child_window(**criterion)`.

But according to my test, sometimes I can get main dialog and continue to operate its controls, sometimes not. I don’t know why, I hope someone can help me or provide another way to get the main dialog of ImageCalculate.exe. Because I have the PID of ImageCalculate.exe, maybe I can get the Process’s main dialog by PID? And then maybe I can check this dialog is displayed or not to confirm this dialog belongs to which Page.exe(If this dialog is displayed, I think this dialog belongs to Page1’s Page.exe’s ImageCalculate.exe).

```
ParentDlg = Desktop(backend="uia").window(best_match="Page1")
// pids contains two pid of ImageCalculate.exe
for pid in pids:
    try:
        criterion = {}
        criterion['class_name_re'] = "AfxFrameOrView*"
        criterion['process']=pid
        ImageCalculate_dialog = parent.child_window(**criterion)
        # I think if ImageCalculate_dialog.writable_props is successful. 
        # Page1’s Page.exe’s ImageCalculate.exe's main dialog is found. 
        # But some times ImageCalculate_dialog.writable_props is failed two times and throws  ElementNotFoundError
        _cname = ImageCalculate_dialog.writable_props
    except pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError:
        continue
    else:
        return ImageCalculate_dialog 


# Now I am trying to use following codes to get main dialog
ImageCalculateApp = Application().connect(process=pid)
dialogs = ImageCalculateApp.windows()
for dialog in dialogs:
    print(dialog)
# When I check print result in console
# I can find "hwndwrapper.DialogWrapper - 'ImageCalculate - Untitled',Afx:00400000:b:00010003:00000006:003908A5"
# But I don't know how to use hwndwrapper.DialogWrapper object,
# who could tell me how to use this object or give me some documents about this object?
```

Comment: `.writable_props` is not what you need. You can find methods descriptions here: https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.controls.hwndwrapper.html Looks like my previous answer didn't help as it's not accepted. So I'd suggest to learn Python better first. Also please provide more details on what is going wrong. It's not clear what phrase "sometimes not" really means. Please post error message or better the full traceback.

Comment: Sometimes not means the writable_props throws exception two times, one time is for PID 1234, one time is for PID 5678. so no dialog is found and my test case can no be executed. so if I want to check ImageCalculate_dialog belongs to which ImageCalculate.exe, how to do that？

Comment: `ImageCalculate_dialog.process_id()`

Comment: Also `criterion['active_only'] = True` or `criterion['found_index'] = 0` might be useful.